# Add a class to the current active link using YUI

Tags: javascript, yui

I got this function in jQuery:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.primary-nav li').each(function() {
    var href = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href');
    if (href === window.location.pathname) {
    jQuery(this).addClass('current');
    }
  });
});
```

but unfortunately I need to do accomplish the same with the YUI library.  Add a class to the a element if the a href is the same as the current active page.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An almost direct translation of the JQuery above would be something like:

```
YUI().use('node', function(){
    Y.all('.primary-nav li').each(function(node){
        var href = node.getAttribute('href');
        if (href === window.location.pathname){
            node.addClass('current');
        }
    });
});
```

However, I would imagine you could do something like:

```
YUI().use('node', function(){
    Y.one('.primary-nav li a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').addClass('current');
});
```

To achieve the same effect.  (code tested only in my head)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```
YUI().use('node', function(){
    Y.all('.primary-nav li').each(function(node){
        var href = node.getAttribute('href');
        node.toggleClass('current', href === window.location.pathname); 
    });
});
```

Adds the class if the second parameter is true, otherwise removes it.